# jquery version 2.2.4 with lightning component version 40

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, locker-service, summer-17

Before summer 17, the jquery version 2.2.4 was working well with locker service. Now, with summer 17, we have locker service enabled automatically. With this, if we update our components to version 40, then again the jquery is not working with the locker service. Has anyone encountered this issue? Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Below is the error screen short,
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Is there a specific method or operation that's not working, or an error message?

Comment: @Florissant53 i have added error screen short in main question. Thanks!

Comment: @thoriyas Can you file a case with salesforce and provide login access to your org? From just looking at the screenshot it seems to be a CSP issue. It isn't clear how Locker Service would cause it. Locker Service doesn't control the CSP of the page, lightning platform does.

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa FYI We have used the lightning component using lightning out app in vf page and that Vf page we have put inside the record detail page.

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa We have filed the case for this issue with Support · Case 16805352

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread, and see if the suggestions there help.  Looks like there might be a couple suggestions:

1. Use a later version of jQuery (3.2.1 is suggested), as version 2.2.4 might try modifying the DOM out of scope (whatever that means, I'm not that familiar with cross domain errors).
2. Downgrade the API version.  Although I think that disables LockerService, and I do all my development with it enabled, so I personally wouldn't do that.

[Cross-Origin Frame Error in Lightning Component embedded in Salesforce Console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173406/cross-origin-frame-error-in-lightning-component-embedded-in-salesforce-console)

Hope this info helps!

Comment: I have looked that but i am worried that it was working with older version and locker service before summer 17. Also 2.2.4 is listed as compliant library here - 
 https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html